# Deleting related NSManagedObjects from custom NSManagedObject class

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have 2 custom NSManagedObject subclasses: `Patient` and `ToDoItem`. There is a one-to-many relationship from `Patient` to `ToDoItem`. Following are the properties of the `Patient` subclass:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *toDoItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * patientIsDeleted;
```

When `patientIsDeleted` value is changed to `1` I want to delete all related toDoItems like this:

```
- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"patientIsDeleted"] && [[self valueForKey:key] isEqualToNumber:@1]) {
    //Code to execute the delete process
    }
}
```

I am having trouble getting the related `toDoItems` when i count the NSSet it returns 0

```
self.toDoItems.count //Returns 0
[[self mutableSetValueForKey:@"toDoItems"] count] //Returns 0
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Can I use the NSSet property to get related objects?

Comment: That is strange. What happens if you NSLog the value of `self.toDoItems`?

Comment: I can't give you a screendump right now. But i tried this and it returns a description over  the relationship and the `Patient` object. But `objects` is empty